# reprints with additional remarks and biblatex-sbl with

Tags: biblatex

In some reprints, there were added sections of forewords, introductions, etc. In German Bibliographies, these additions have to be mentioned. As far as I see, the `biblatex-sbl` style has not a feature to mention it, or?

For instance, there is this book

> Name, Surname: History: Contribution. London, 1908. Ndr., Lens: Avant, 1977.

and in this book, an introduction has been added by Prof. XYZ. In this case, it is usually to give this annotation (in notes and in the bibliography):

> Name, Surname: History: Contribution. London, 1908. Ndr. with an introduction by Prof. XYZ, Lens: Avant, 1977.

Has someone an idea how I can have such a result? I have asked this question in another forum, but since a week, I have not received any answer.

My second question: The abbreviation "Ndr." for the reprint (in German: Neudruck) is very untypical. It is possible to replace this abbreviation "Ndr." with the common "ND"?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Name.1908,
  author = {Name, Surname},
  title = {History},
  subtitle = {Contribution},
  shorttitle = {History},
  location = {Lens},
  origlocation = {London},
  publisher = {Avant},
  origdate = {1908},
  date = {1977},
}

\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setmainlanguage[variant=new]{german} 

\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[style=sbl, backend=biber, 
  sblfootnotes=false, ibidpage=true, 
  sorting=nyvt, 
  url=false, isbn=false, doi=false, 
  clearlang=false, 
  uniquename=false]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite{Name.1908}.
Filler text \autocite{Name.1908}.
\printbiblist{abbreviations}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## New Answer based on comments below

Given your comments below, that reprints are uniquely different to anything else that `biblatex-sbl` produces, I'd do things in a completely different way.

You will see that note output is identical to bibliography output when `relatedtype={reprint}`. But for all other entry types, the standard `biblatex-sbl` behaviour should be preserved.

### MWE

See comments for what is going on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
% use note for original publication information so it isn't put in parentheses
@book{Familyname.1977,
  author = {Familyname, Givenname},
  title = {History},
  subtitle = {Contribution},
  shorttitle = {History},
  note = {London, 1908},
  related = {Familyname.1977.repr},
  relatedtype = {reprint},
}
@book{Familyname.1977.repr,
  note = {with an introduction by Prof\adddot\space XYZ},
  location = {Lens},
  publisher = {Avant},
  date = {1977}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[style=sbl, language=ngerman, sblfootnotes=false,
  ibidtracker=constrict, ibidpage=true, sorting=nyvt, url=false, isbn=false,
  doi=false, clearlang=false, uniquename=false]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% Change reprint abbreviation to ND
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  reprint = {ND}
}

% Put reprint information in parentheses and change beginning punctuation to a
% space
\newcommand*{\begrelateddelimreprint}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{related:reprint}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% Set \newunitpunct to comma and remove parentheses around publication info
\renewbibmacro*{related:reprint}[1]{%
  \entrydata*{#1}{%
    \usedriver
      {\renewbibmacro*{related:init}{}%
       \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%
       \renewbibmacro*{parens+publisher+location+date}{%
         \newunit
         \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}}
      {\ifbibliography
         {\thefield{entrytype}}
         {cite:\thefield{entrytype}}}}}

% use family, given and change \newunitpunct to a point just for related
% entries (I have serious misgivings about this as it seems very
% inconsistent.)
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretobibmacro{cite}
  {\iffieldequalstr{relatedtype}{reprint}
     {\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}%
      \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}}
     {}}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite{Familyname.1977}.
Filler text \autocite{Familyname.1977}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

---

## Original Answer

Here's a partial solution, but there is a bug in `biblatex`.

Your request to have *with and introduction by* in English may almost warrant a separate question, as I'm not sure if setting the `langid` of the reprint information is the best way of doing this.

I think the best way to set up your bib entries is like this:

```
@book{Familyname.1977,
  author = {Familyname, Givenname},
  title = {History},
  subtitle = {Contribution},
  shorttitle = {History},
  location = {London},
  date = {1908},
  related = {Familyname.1977.repr},
  relatedtype = {reprint}
}
@book{Familyname.1977.repr,
  introduction = {{Prof\adddot\space XYZ}},
  location = {Lens},
  publisher = {Avant},
  date = {1977},
  langid = {american}
}
```

The theory of including the `langid` field is to ensure that strings in the reprint are printed in English, but strings in the main entry are printed in your main document language of German. This also requires the addition of `autolang=other, language=auto` to the main `biblatex` options (and adding `american` to your `babel` options). The problem is that this breaks strings everywhere with `biblatex-sbl` and they are all printed in English. I'll try and find the bug and fix it. In the mean time, I've provided a second MWE using the `note` field (which might be a better option anyway) to achieve the output you want. (In your MWE, no difference is seen, but if your book used `editor` instead of `author`, you'd see that the *ed.* is printed rather than *Hrsg.*) See https://github.com/dcpurton/biblatex-sbl/issues/106. Turns out this is actually a bug in `biblatex`. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/903.

One other problem is that out of the box this won't print *with and introduction by* as there is a test to make sure the `title` field is defined. We can fix this by redefining the macro `byauthor/byeditor+others/bytranslator+others` as follows:

```
\renewbibmacro*{byauthor/byeditor+others/bytranslator+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{ifbooktitleormaintitle}
    {\usebibmacro{byeditor/bytranslator}}
    {\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}}
```

I haven't tested to see if this redefinition breaks other things yet (but if it does, it would only be in fairly obscure cases that might not affect you). I'll look into this further.

You can redefine the `reprint` string using `\DefineBibliographyStrings`:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  reprint = {ND}
}
```

Finally, I recommend using `babel` and `lualatex` instead of `polyglossia`, which does not work well with `biblatex`.

So the full MWE becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Familyname.1977,
  author = {Familyname, Givenname},
  title = {History},
  subtitle = {Contribution},
  shorttitle = {History},
  location = {London},
  date = {1908},
  related = {Familyname.1977.repr},
  relatedtype = {reprint},
  langid = {ngerman}
}
@book{Familyname.1977.repr,
  introduction = {{Prof\adddot\space XYZ}},
  location = {Lens},
  publisher = {Avant},
  date = {1977},
  langid = {american}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[american,ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[style=sbl, autolang=other, language=auto, sblfootnotes=false,
  ibidpage=true, sorting=nyvt, url=false, isbn=false, doi=false,
  clearlang=false, uniquename=false]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  reprint = {ND}
}

\newbibmacro*{byauthor/byeditor+others/bytranslator+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{ifbooktitleormaintitle}
    {\usebibmacro{byeditor/bytranslator}}
    {\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite{Familyname.1977}.
Filler text \autocite{Familyname.1977}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

---

Workaround using the `note` field:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Familyname.1977,
  author = {Familyname, Givenname},
  title = {History},
  subtitle = {Contribution},
  shorttitle = {History},
  location = {London},
  date = {1908},
  related = {Familyname.1977.repr},
  relatedtype = {reprint},
}
@book{Familyname.1977.repr,
  note = {with an \ifbibliography{introduction}{intro\adddot} by Prof\adddot\space XYZ},
  location = {Lens},
  publisher = {Avant},
  date = {1977}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[style=sbl, sblfootnotes=false, ibidpage=true, sorting=nyvt,
  url=false, isbn=false, doi=false, clearlang=false,
  uniquename=false]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  reprint = {ND}
}

\renewbibmacro*{byauthor/byeditor+others/bytranslator+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{ifbooktitleormaintitle}
    {\usebibmacro{byeditor/bytranslator}}
    {\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite{Familyname.1977}.
Filler text \autocite{Familyname.1977}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Intuitively, I'd have said that *Nachdruck* is much more common than *Neudruck*, but I'm not in the field of Biblical studies or a related field and can't say anything about the practices there (we mathematicians usually don't even bother with *Nachdruck* hints in the bibliography at all). Apparently Wikipedia suggests (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachdruck) that back in the olden days a *Neudruck* was a legitimate reprinting of a work by a publisher with the rights for publication, whereas a *Nachdruck* was unauthorised and possibly of worse quality (*Raubdruck*). ...

Comment: ...  This distinction is not present any more for most people, but I don't know if some fields stick to this tradition. I should say that I find *Nachdr.* the most intuitive abbreviation of *Nachdruck* and that *ND* with two capital letters looks very unusual to my eyes.

Comment: @moewe, thanks. I might check in with the person who gave the default translation for `biblatex-sbl`.

Comment: Thanks! moewe is correct by saying that both terms are interchangeable today. For Biblical Studies, I have never seen this abbreviation "Ndr."; "ND" is common. I see two problems with the "introduction" field: 1) This "with an introduction by Prof. XYZ" will be translated into German - that is quite wrong, since this new part of the reprint belongs to the title and titles still remained untranslated. 2) The position is misleading. This "with an introduction by Prof. XYZ" should be set immediately after "ND" so that the reader knows that this part can be found only in the reprint.

Comment: @user192316, yes, I'm looking into it. It should be possible to do things nicely I think. The simple `origdate`, `origlocation`, and `origpublisher`, is really only suitable when it's a recent reprint with no changes to the book but under a different publisher (See §6.2.17) of the *SBL Handbook of Style*.

Comment: @user192316, see my updated answer now.

Comment: @moewe, do you have an opinion on printing *with an introduction by* in English and the best way to do this?

Comment: Well, if the *with an introduction by ...* bit is supposed to be an immutable part of the title, `introduction` and bibstrings are not all that useful. I would just go with `titleaddon` or `note`. If you ask me, I quite like the flexibility `introduction` gives me, but if this is not desired there is no point in sticking with it.

Comment: Again thanks! The method with "note" is better praticable for me. There is one issue that I don't like in the Bibliography: "Normal" reprints have this format: Familyname, Givenname. History: Contribution. London, 1908 (ND Lens: Avant, 1977). In added reprints, the brackets were missing - is it possible to change it to this format: Familyname, Givenname. History: Contribution. London, 1908 (ND with an introduction by Prof. XYZ, (not point!) Lens: Avant, 1977).

Comment: @user192316 Oooo! Interesting. As I look at the *SBL Handbook* more closely it looks like it should be like this: For notes: "1. Givenname Familyname, *History: Contribution* (London, 1908; ND, with an intro. by
Prof. XYZ; Lens: Avant, 1977)." And for the Bibliography it should be "Familyname, Givenname. *History: Contribution*. London, 1908. ND, with an
introduction by Prof. XYZ. Lens: Avant, 1977." See Sasson on pages 10 and 182 of the handbook.

Comment: @user192316, I'll fix the parentheses in the main `biblatex-sbl` package and use a semicolon to separate items by default.

Comment: @user192316, can you clarify a bit more what you want in both note and bibliography? Is this what you want? In notes: "¹Givenname Familyname, *History: Contribution* (London, 1908; ND, with an intro. by Prof. XYZ, Lens: Avant, 1977)." And in bibliography: "Familyname, Givenname. History: Contribution. London, 1908 (ND, with an introduction by Prof. XYZ, Lens: Avant, 1977)."

Comment: I want in both note and bibliography this format:  "Familyname, Givenname. History: Contribution. London, 1908 (ND, with an introduction by Prof. XYZ, Lens: Avant, 1977)."

Comment: @user192316, I assume you've already changed the name format in notes away from "Givenname Familyname" then?

Comment: @user192316, this is *far* from SBL style. The problem with `biblatex-sbl` is that it is designed to conform to the SBL Handbook of Style as closely as I can make it. And it is not always easy to customise. Now I'm all confused what you want for normal references without reprints. Do they look like what you get from `biblatex-sbl` by default?

Comment: In this case, the sbl-style for the reprinted titles with notes is weird and untypical for German notes. The normal references without reprints are untouched (i.e. not customized).

Comment: @user192316 But In your example, *everything* is different for notes. You have different order of name (given family → family, given); different punctuation between items (comma → point). *Surely* this can't be right?

Comment: I was not aware of the different order of name; it should be "Familyname, Givenname" and between the items, there should be a point. Only after "Prof. XYZ" should be set a comma; In conclusion, I want this format in the notes and the biblioraphy fro reprints with additional material: Familyname, Givenname. History: Contribution. London, 1908 (ND with an introduction by Prof. XYZ, Lens: Avant, 1977).

Comment: @user192316, see my new answer now.

Comment: Thanks! It works well.